# I need to use an object created in one static method in another static method but have issue calling it

Tags: java, object, methods

(This is a repost of a previous question I have where I modified the code so it is much easier to understand.)

```
public class LaptopSaleApp{
     public static void main(String[] args){
          selectLaptop();
          selectSupportOptions(laptopOrder);//This parameter cannot be resolved into a variable
     }
     public static void selectLaptop(){
          LaptopSalesOrder laptopOrder = new LaptopSalesOrder("Dell Latitude", 1399.00);
     }
     public static void selectSupportOptions(LaptopSalesOrder laptopOrder){
          laptopOrder.setBasicIndicator(true);
     }
}
```

I need two static methods here. The object has to be declared in the first method, and then is used in the second method for the setBasicIndicator setter. I then need to call both methods in my main to run the program, but I don't know what to put in the parameters for the method in the main.

Comment: `public static void selectLaptop(){` needs to return something, `public static LaptopSalesOrder selectLaptop(){` for example, then you can just call `selectSupportOptions(selectLaptop());`.  This comes down to [Defining Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) and [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can't quite do this if the object is *declared* in the first method.

Here's what you *should* do:

```
     public static void main(String[] args){
          LaptopSalesOrder laptopOrder = selectLaptop();
          selectSupportOptions(laptopOrder);
     }
     public static LaptopSalesOrder selectLaptop(){
          return new LaptopSalesOrder("Dell Latitude", 1399.00);
     }
     public static void selectSupportOptions(LaptopSalesOrder laptopOrder){
          laptopOrder.setBasicIndicator(true);
     }
```